How to fix peeling/bubbling paint in old home without stripping or too much sanding
long story short:
I have an old home, there are a lot of places on trim where the paint is bubbling, or there are thin parts where you can see there was previously chipped/peeling paint that was improperly painted over. The caveat is, is that at some point in the layers there is lead paint. I'd love to not have to sand down very far, but I suspect that's the only way.
Any advice for filling in these low spots without sanding down flat? Same goes for the bubbles. If there is no other proper solution, any tricks to make it more acceptable? Not our forever home.



The second pictures like moisture problems.  A good long lasting paint job requires quite a bit of prep work first.  Sanding, cleaning, removing all loose paint.  It is just a waste of paint and your work if the prep is not done well before.  If you do not want to do the work, get painters in to do it.

Yeah, obviously, if I don't want to do the work I would hire someone to do it. The key is to find someone who will take all the precautions dealing with lead paint, at a price point that makes sense for general maintenance, not an upgrade. Unfortunately that's hard to verify and ensure at the end of the day. Thus my asking if there are any good alternatives.

With lead paint you want to limit the sanding, and use strippers.  Masks, drop clothes to hold all paint that comes down, good vacuuming/washing of all surfaces after to make sure no old paint remains.  Lead paint is basically safe if left alone on surfaces, it is when it gets into you or kids/pets/outdoor animals, that is the danger to health.

Do you know that there is lead paint in there? Lead paints were phased out a few decades ago in some locations. You can get kits to test for lead paint.

@AndrewMorton Yep, definitely lead. Been tested and confirmed. Old house built in the 20s. All woodwork around the house has lead underneath new paint. Oddly enough, the doors do NOT have lead paint.

If the lead paint is bonded well to stuff underneath, it can be painted over, after cleaning.  The problem is with little kids that can chew on the paint(I was sticking stuff into outlets, so know we are weird).  No kids makes life easier, if paint is well bonded.
